# How to do select multiple records based on max version using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have records such like this

```
id  name     number version
---------------------------
1   NewYork     1     1 
2   LosAngeles  1     2 
3   Seatle      1     3
4   Toronto     2     1
5   Ottawa      2     2
```

I want to select only the records with highest version within the same number

So I wrote query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM city c 
WHERE c.[version] = (SELECT Max([version])
                     FROM [city] c2 
                     WHERE c2.number = c.number)
```

and it would return

```
id  name     number version      
---------------------------
3   Seatle      1     3
5   Ottawa      2     2
```

How do I write that in linq with Entity Framework?

```
db.cities.where(c => c.version == (????))
```

I don't know how Entity Framework would work for this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `GroupBy` to group by the `number` and then `OrderBy` the record with the highest `version`:

```
var result = db.cities.GroupBy(item => item.number)
                      .Select(grouping => grouping.OrderByDescending(item => item.version)
                                                  .First());
```

Comment: @nanobots - If your query is slow then see what is the generated query by linq and check the execution plan. You might want to add indexes on the fields you are grouping by - in this case the `number`

Comment: yeah I guess I'll give it a try. Maybe is just the initialization in the entity framework's initial overhead

Comment: @nanobots - Even with the magic of EF db logic needs tuning and fitting both the code and the database to each other and to requirements. BTW - see update

Comment: no original sql actually returns correct result. it has been tested. It seem to be a sql thing if you do select max in the inner query it will return all the max versions on unique number. It surprised me at first too but it definitely works. tested it over and over again. the result returned table is actually based on what my original query returned.

Comment: why do we need the selectMany at the end it seem to return a list of record without the selectMany from what I feel

Answer (score 2):

```
var maxVersionCities = db.cities
    .GroupBy(c => c.number)
    .Select(grp => grp
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.version)
        .First())
    .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```

Comment: No need for the second grouping.. and also will not work. you ywill need to do `SelectMany(grp => grp.SelectMany(inner => inner))`... and after correcting that it will basically be my answer...

Comment: @GiladGreen what if multiple cities with the same number also have the same highest version?

Comment: is not possible I made it unique on the table number + version

Comment: I know  using groupby it work. But when ever I use groupby in entity framework it just seem sooo much slower. the callback literally takes about 5 seconds when the query runs for like instant. Is there any reason that why groupby is just so much slower than the query itself in entity framework.